# Кнопка Play в уведомлениях

Tags: android

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку Play в уведомлениях таким образом

В методе showNotification() пишу так

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
playIntent.putExtra("stream", stream);
playIntent.putExtra("radio", radio);
playIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
PendingIntent pPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, playIntent, 0);
```

А в методе onStartCommand() так

```
if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;
            showNotification();
            Log.d(myLog, stream + "");
            ExoPlayer.startExoPlayer(stream, this);
        }
```

Выдает ошибку а именно stream оказывается null. Как будет правильнее это реализовать?

Comment: Где код, как вы извлекаете stream из Extra?

Answer (score 0):

После проверки интента, извлекайте extra

```
if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        isPlay = true;
        showNotification();
        String stream = intent.getStringExtra("stream", "");
        Log.d(myLog, stream + "");
        ExoPlayer.startExoPlayer(stream, this);
    }
```

Comment: Я до проверки извлекал так stream = intent.getStringExtra("stream")

Comment: без второго параметра по-умолчанию?

Comment: да.. его не указывал. если второй параметр пишу компилятор ругается

Comment: попробуйте поместить извлечение после проверки, указать умолчание, и посмотреть что выдаст лог, если параметр по-умлочанию, значит нужно проверить переменную которую в екстра помещаете.

Comment: так если указать со вторым параметром, вообще не компилируется. ваш код скопировал я просто

Comment: да, ошибочка вышла со вторым параметром, перепутал с bunlde. Так а зачем вы в onStartCommand() вызываете showNotification() с запуском сервиса снова по кругу? Сервис запускается только через метод  showNotification() или есть другие запуски? тогда без проверки интента конечно null будет

Comment: в методе showNotification в конце вызывается startForeground. а в активити где запускается сепвис такой код     public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("stream", stream);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("radio", radio);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }